# Building a raw contract transaction with ethers.js

Tags: dapp-development, raw-transaction, ethers.js

Can't find any good documentation on creating a raw transaction with contract data in ethers.js. The equivalent in web3 is adding the `encodeABI` on the data property. Any guidance on this?

This isn't working:

```
data = myContract.interface.functions.myFunction(value);
const tx = {
   ...
   data
   ...
}
```

It doesn't seem to recognize this is a function (even though i see the data property there).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the populateTransaction mechanism documented here: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/

So specifically, that'd be:

```js
const data = await myContract.populateTransaction.myFunction(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you can use populateTransaction in Ether.js is:

```
const contract = new Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, CONTRACT_ABI, Wallet);
const params = [value];
const action = 'myFunction';
const unsignedTx = await contract.populateTransaction[action](...params);
```

Then you can simply sign and send your transaction like:

```
await Wallet.sendTransaction(unsignedTx);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that in v6 (June 2023) the `populateTransaction` order has been flipped so you need to call it in this order `contract[action].populateTransaction(...params);`