# Extracting the signature for a transaction without executing the call

Tags: solidity, signature

I am curious if it's possible to extract a signed transaction, without executing the call completely, against a certain function in a contract? The extracted signature is then saved and fully executed at a later stage.

**Scenario:**

Setup:

1. contract 1 = `Game`
2. contract 2 = `Impersonator`
3. actor 1 = `Player`
4. actor 2 = `Handler`

The `Game` contract has a payable function called `Roll`:

`contract Game { function roll() public payable { // roll a radom number } }`

The `Player` wants to call the `roll` function but goes through the `Imporsonator` contract.

The `Impersonator` contract has a `saveRollTrx` payable function that saves the signed trx from `Player` towards the function 'roll'

`contract Impersonator { function saveRollTrx() public payable { uint256 sig = gameContract.roll(); // somehow extract the signature without executing the call? } }`

The `Imporsonator` contract would also have a second function that the `Handler` actor could execute with the saved signature towards the `roll` function on the `Game` contract on behalf of `Player`.

Comment: in ethers call populateTransaction: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84561/building-a-raw-contract-transaction-with-ethers-js

Comment: @HananBeer, this looks a bit like what I am looking for. Two questions: **1)** Can this to be done within the Solidity contract itself? **2)** So the player executes the `populateTransaction` and I can then execute the `sendTransaction`? It doesn't have to be the user executing the `sendTransaction` as well?

Comment: use abi.encodeWithSignature or the likes: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/112562/how-do-you-pass-abi-encoded-parameters-to-abi-encodewithsignature-abi-encodewi